# How can I get the list of potential workflow actions for the current user?

Tags: workflow, liferay-6

I would like to embed workflow steps inside and interface: when I display a Milestone object (workflow enabled), I would like to offer the user the choice to trigger the actions available for that specific object (those that appear in the action button in the workflow portlets).

Can someone lead me in the right direction ?

I am using liferay 6.1 GA3 CE.

Many thanks,
Alain

Comment: I am not clear with your question , but `WorkflowTaskManagerUtil.getNextTransitionNames(company.getCompanyId(), user.getUserId(), workflowTask.getWorkflowTaskId());` line of code may help you.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. Ideed helps, but I am very new to this workflow framework and am a bit lost... How do I get the workflowTask ? I assume from my reading that I have to rely on the serviceContext, but how ?